# Pausar y reproducir reproductor de video con botones usando un VideoView

Tags: java, android-studio, videoview

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de reproductor de video en Android Studio. En la aplicación se pueden seleccionar tres videos mediante un spinner.
También tengo tres botones uno de play, otro de pausa y otro de stop.

Mi problema es que al pulsar pausa y luego volver al play el video no se me reproduce donde se pauso sino desde el principio.

Me gustaría saber cómo obtengo la posición del video cuando pulso pausa.
Muchas gracias de antemano, les dejo el código java del reproductor.

```
public class Reproductor extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner sp_video;
    private VideoView vv_video;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        sp_video = findViewById(R.id.sp_video);
        vv_video = findViewById(R.id.vv_video);
    }

    public void playVideo (View vista){
        String ruta = "";
        int select = sp_video.getSelectedItemPosition();
            if (select == 0) {
                ruta = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video1;
            } else if (select == 1) {
                ruta = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video2;
            } else if (select == 2) {
                ruta = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video3;
            }
            vv_video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(ruta));
            vv_video.start();
    }

    public void pauseVideo (View vista){
        vv_video.pause();
    }

    public void stopVideo (View vista){
        vv_video.stopPlayback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Me gustaría saber cómo obtengo la posición del video cuando pulso
> pausa.

Puedes usar el método [getCurrentPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView#getCurrentPosition()) del VideoView.

---

Lo que debes realizar es obtener la posición donde quedó pausada usando el método [getCurrentPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView#getCurrentPosition()) que devolverá un valor entero, este valor lo usarías para mover la cabeza lectora a esa posición usando [seekTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView#seekTo(int)) y vuelves a reproducir usando [start()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView#start()).

```
 private int position = 0;

 public void pauseVideo (View vista){
      vv_video.pause();
      position = vv_video.getCurrentPosition();
 }

  public void stopVideo (View vista){
      vv_video.stopPlayback();
      position  = 0;
 }

public void playVideo (View vista){
        if(position > 0){ //Reproduce video en pausa.
           vv_video.seekTo(position);
           vv_video.start();
           return;
        }

        String ruta = "";
        int select = sp_video.getSelectedItemPosition();
            if (select == 0) {
                ruta = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video1;
            } else if (select == 1) {
                ruta = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video2;
            } else if (select == 2) {
                ruta = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video3;
            }
            vv_video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(ruta));
            vv_video.start();
    }
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! Ahora si que funciona.